# is there similar to standalone in vueJS

Tags: vue.js

I'm asking if we have similar attribute as standalone in vuejs. 
I want to add items in certifications. 
Here is the button  add :

```
<l-button  @click="Add()"><i class="fa fa-plus"> </i></l-button>
```

The add function:

```
        Add() {
            this.certifications.push( item);
            this.newItemAdded = true
        },


 <div v-for="(item,index) in certifications">
      <fg-input type="text" required
                  :label="$t('candidate.certification.title')"
                  :placeholder="$t('candidate.certification.title')" 
                  :disabled="disableIt && !newItemAdded ">
        </fg-input>
  </div>
```

My problem is that when i add new item, the previous input also is enabled.

I want to know if there is somathing similar to standalone( like  angular) in vuejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the `index` and `length of certifications`

```
<div v-for="(item,index) in certifications">
      <fg-input type="text" required
                  :label="$t('candidate.certification.title')"
                  :placeholder="$t('candidate.certification.title')" 
                  :disabled="(index+1!==certifications.length)">
       </fg-input>
</div>
```

> and when you need **edit button**:

```
  data() {
    return {
      certifications: [],
      editableIndex: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    Add() {
      ...
    },
    Edit(index) {
      this.editableIndex = index
    },
  }
}
```

and in template

```
<template>
   <div>
    <div v-for="(item,index) in certifications">
      <fg-input type="text" required
                  :label="$t('candidate.certification.title')"
                  :placeholder="$t('candidate.certification.title')" 
                  :disabled="(index+1!==certifications.length&&editableIndex===null) || editableIndex===index">
      </fg-input>
      <l-button  @click="Edit(index)"><i class="fa fa-pen"> </i></l-button>
    </div>
    <l-button  @click="Add()"><i class="fa fa-plus"> </i></l-button>
   </div>
</template>
```

Comment: But when i try to edit  in item, all the  items inputs  are enabled. How can i refers  only to the current item in the list ?

Comment: you must be add `data() { return { editableIndex: null } }` and add button to edit with index (click action must be `@click='editableIndex = index'`) and then change `:disabled` attr to `(editableIndex===null&&index+1!==certifications.length)||editableIndex===index`

Comment: I didn't get well, could you please  provide me the full example ?